# ExpressJS, NodeJs, and MongoDB CRUD Skeleton - Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, homebrew, crud

I have recently started working with MongoDB and had it working for a small web test with node JS However. I new my implementation wasn't following a decent MVC structure. I began searching and found this website and read through it. It's implementation look good as well as following a good MVS skeleton structure.

[Express/NodeJS/MongoDB CRUD Skeleton](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/complete-expressjs-nodejs-mongodb-crud-skeleton)

I got to the part where he says 'HOORAY! We've got a functioning web server that is talking to Mongo. Part 1 is accomplished." Unfortunately, I went the local host specified and it says the 'site cannot be reached'. I am still fairly new to NodeJs, Mongo and Express and cannot figure out why it is not working.
I am not sure if I have done a step wrong time and time again which I doubt or if there something is missing that is stopping me from having it working.

The part before it says:

> Awesome. Now to test it's all working in the terminal type npm start and you shouldn't see any errors:
>
> ```
> kcoleman-mbp:nodewebapp kcoleman$ npm start
>
> > nodewebapp@0.0.1 start /Users/kcoleman/Documents/projects/nodewebapp
> > node ./bin/www
> ```

That part I get the same outcome with:

```
nodewebApp and node./bin/www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page says to navigate to 127.0.0.0:3000, but the localhost usualy defaults to 127.0.0.1. I didn't see any code in the page where he defines the port to 127.0.0.0.

So try connecting to **127.0.0.1:3000**.

Coming to `nodewebApp and node./bin/www`, it could be because the command might be present in pacakge.json. If you delete the nodewebApp from package.json, you won't be seeing the same in the command.

Comment: WOW, I had a feeling it was a port issue but I thought the default port was 127.0.0.0? If you know a good link or book or resource on ports that you could add to the bottom of your answer that would be great for newbies who are interested in this post. THANKS.                                                  Note: Sorry I took long been overloaded with other work.